# why angular-datatables plugin buttons doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am using angular-datatables from the following resource: http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome

I am trying to run the example of 'with buttons' from here: 
    http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withButtons

I am doing everything exactly like in the example but apparently I don't see any buttons on the table and I should see them.
    Any clue why it is acting like this.

**Update:**

I can see only custom button without **excel** or **pdf** button.I still have a problem not all buttons are presented.

```
My code is here:
[http://codepen.io/Barak/pen/aNPZgN][3]

[http://codepen.io/Barak/pen/aNPZgN][3]
```

Comment: For starters, you are not using the `dt-options` property...

Comment: ok my mistake I forgot to add it to current example,but still it doesn't work.

Comment: it looks like you may just have dependency errors, the console is giving an error saying it doesn't recognize your buttons. Might want to double check you are using the correct versions of everything. Also maybe try locally first, so you aren't dependent on cdns

Comment: I have tried it locally at first! I have upload it for stackoverflow because there is no other way to present the problem.

Comment: I don't see any errors,which error do you talking about?

Comment: I need the excel button to work properly.

Comment: Because you removed the first couple buttons that are working on their example, columnsToggle and so on. If you add them in, you will see an error saying unkown button type. This leads me to believe you are missing or have incorrect dependancies, because the example works on their documentation. Check the versions and the order you are loading your scripts, and make sure all of them are actually loaded.

Comment: All scripts are loaded properly, I have checked it manually by my self.Please help me, try it for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include buttons.html5.js, buttons.flash.js to your html.